# Scipy Linear Programming Rational Numbers

Tags: python, scipy, linear-programming

`scipy.optimize.linprog` seems to be a wrapper around a C/Fortran library that always uses floating point numbers regardless of the input type.

```
from scipy import optimize as opt
from fractions import Fraction
import numpy as np

lp = opt.linprog

def frac(arr):
    "convert array or number to rational form"
    if isinstance(arr, int) or isinstance(arr, float):
        return Fraction(arr)
    else:
        return list(map(frac, arr))

A_ub = frac([
    [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    [ 4, 5, 6]
])

A_ub = np.array(A_ub, dtype=object)

b_ub = frac( [ 1, 2 ] )
b_ub = np.array(b_ub, dtype=object)

c = frac( [ -1, -2, -3 ])
c = np.array(c, dtype=object)

result = lp(A_ub=A_ub, b_ub=b_ub, c=c)
print result.x.dtype
```

prints `float64`

Is there a similar library with a different solver in numpy/ scipy that is able to manipulate arbitrary python objects and use their methods `+, -, *, /` instead of coercing everything to floating point?

Comment: Not as far as I know.

Comment: Years ago I taught the Dantzig's simplex algorithm to students without computers or even calculators.  How about trying to implement that using your `Fraction` objects?

Comment: @hpaulj This might be the wrong place to ask, but do you know off hand if there is a method similar to the simplex method that 1) only considers points with rational components if you start with rational components and 2) does not have to start initially at a feasible point?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet: what you are asking about is precisely the way [julia](https://julialang.org)'s [JuMP](http://www.juliaopt.org/JuMP.jl) library works. To my knowledge this is a unique feature of Julia to define the algorithms in a very high-level terms and use operations defined for a given type to perform them efficiently.